# while creating azure data factory getting error "The specified resource name 'bhana54' is already in use. Resource names must be globally unique.""

Tags: azure-data-factory

while creating data factory getting the below error even I have tried multiple unique names
{
"status": "Failed",

```
"error": {

    "code": "Data Factory Name In Use",

    "message": "The specified resource name 'bhana54' is already in use. Resource names must be globally unique."

}
```

}

Comment: This is not a question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to improve your post. This is likely to be a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The error message clearly explains the reason for the failure as `he specified resource name 'bhana54' is already in use. Resource names must be globally unique.`

> In order to resolve this issue try to change the data factory name to different name (Which should be globally unique).

Example: I had a ADF named `chepra`, If I try to create new ADF with the same name it will throw the same error and to resolve this issue I had created ADF name as `chepra123`.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Azure Data Factory - naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/naming-rules).